# Intel XDK Browser Error

Tags: intel-xdk

I don't know if you have encountered this problem before but I am trying to test my application using Live Layout Editing Running and when I try to click on either View in a Chrome Window or Firefox, it keeps telling me Browser not Installed..

My Intel XDK version is 1332

Answer (score 0):

We are aware of this problem. For some people the solution found here works: https://forums.html5dev-software.intel.com/viewtopic.php?f=34&t=7346#p27768 -- unfortunately, that is not working for everyone. We hope to have a more complete solution in the next significant release.